# what are the values of a and b?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let  be a random variable with probability distribution function
() =y/2 , ∀ 0 ≤  ≤ 2
Let  be another random variable such that  =  + . If the lower quartile of  is 0 and
the upper quartile of  is 1, then what are the values of  and b?

i got the cdf as y^2/4
i also integrated x=a+by from 0-.25 and eqauted it to 0 and from .75 to 1 and equated it to 1. but i am not getting anything useful from this.
i am getting PDF of x as x/2b

Comment: How can we help you? Have you evaluated the cdf of $Y$?

Comment: it would be great, if you could guide me a little as to how to approach such kind of questions.

Comment: Now you have the cdf of $f(y),$ what is the value of the cdf at $y=2$? I get $F(2) = 2,$ what do you get? I suggest to check the problem more carefully, something is wrong here.

Comment: my sincere appologies, i have now corrected the question

Comment: The two equations are $P(a+bY≤0)=0.25$ and $P(a+bY≤1)=0.75$. They are equivalent to $P(Y≤−\frac{a}b)=0.25$ and $P(Y≤\frac{1−a}b)=0.75$. Is it comprehensible and can you proceed?

Comment: yes, thank you so much,from the first equation i am getting a^2=b^2, and from the 2nd i am getting (1-a/b)^2=3, but when i solve these two i dont seem to get the correct answer. @callculus

Comment: @xyz The second equation should by $\left(\frac{1-a}{b}\right)^2=3$. With the first equation I get the solution $a=b=\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{2}$

Comment: yes excatly, but the answer given is a=b=1/2

Comment: Then I have to think about it further.

Answer (score 1):

Because the transformation is monotonic, you can just find the lower quartile and upper quartile of $y$, then transform that to $x$.  That gives you two equations in the two unknowns $a,b$.  You don't need to find a distribution function for $x$, though you can.